# Figuring out how class Scanner and its exceptions work together in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am looking at the example in *How to Program in Java, 7e*. 
User inputs the data manually into object of class `AccountRecord record`

```
AccountRecord record = new AccountRecord();
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
while ( input.hasNext() ) // loop until end-of-file indicator
      {
         try // output values to file
         {
            // retrieve data to be output
            record.setAccount( input.nextInt() ); // read account number
            record.setFirstName( input.next() ); // read first name
            record.setLastName( input.next() ); // read last name
            record.setBalance( input.nextDouble() ); // read balance

         .............................................................

         catch ( NoSuchElementException elementException )
         {
            System.err.println( "Invalid input. Please try again." );
            input.nextLine(); // discard input so user can try again
         } // end catch
      }
```

I have hard time figuring out how `catch ( NoSuchElementException elementException )` works. According to Java Documentation, NoSuchElementException  is

> Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that
>   there are no more elements in the enumeration.

So, why it would also throw an exception in case type mismatch between expected and what is actually entered, such as for `record.setAccount(input.nextInt())`, user inputs some text string?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For type mismatch problems, you should catch [`InputMismatchException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html). Since it inherits from `NoSuchElementException`, you *will* catch it by catching a `NoSuchElementException` (so the code as it is will catch it and work as expected). To me, that's a strange inheritance relationship, though.... Certainly does not represent an `is-a` relationship.

If you really want to differentiate both cases, catch an `InputMismatchException` *before* a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Why should be InputMismatchException be before NoSuchElementException ? According to Java Doc `public class InputMismatchException extends NoSuchElementException`. So there is a clear is-a relationship between two classes. Or I am I missing something ! Thanks!

Comment: Because catch blocks are evaluated _in order_, so if an `InputMismatchException` is thrown, it will be caught by the intended block, and not by the more general `NoSuchElementException` block.

Comment: Yes you're right about the inheritance... All I'm saying is that _conceptually_ I don't think `InputMismatchException` should inherit from `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 1):

Well each of the:
    input.nextInt(); can throw the NoSuchElementException

if no other element is present.

Your Scanner object is actually an Enumeration.

From the javadoc:

```
Throws:    
 InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular  expression, or is out of range

NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted 

IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

Comment: Thanks! I just looked over docs http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html, and indeed found out that nextXYZ() functions throw exceptions !

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Assingnment {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
    System.out.println("Enter a text: ");
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    String userinput= scan.next();
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Wrong input");
}
}
```